# Rerender funnel highcharts with new data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, highcharts

I am using highcharts in my MVC3 application and I am trying to refresh once the data is modified but the chart doesnot refresh.

I am drawing the chart as follows:-

```
function initializeChart() {

        chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'funnel'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Deal Funnel Stats',
                x: -50
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                buttons: { 
                    exportButton: {
                        enabled:false
                    },
                    printButton: {
                        enabled:false
                    }

                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b> ({point.y:,.0f})',
                        color: 'black',
                        softConnector: true
                    },
                    neckWidth: '0%',
                    neckHeight: '0%'

                    //-- Other available options
                    // height: pixels or percent
                    // width: pixels or percent
                }
            },
            series: [{
                data: @Html.Raw(Model.seriesData)
                }]
        });
    }
```

**Model.seriesData** is coming from the the class.

Once the data is refreshed i want to reinitialize the chart with new data but it is again drawing the same chart.

**Update**:

The data I am having first time is:

[image: data for 1st time]

The data I am having second time is:

[image: data for second time]

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: But `@Html.Raw(Model.seriesData)` variable is set on server side once client load page. Then when you update data on server, client will get updated data only when reload page. How to resolve that? Create AJAX call which will fetch updated data from server and then update chart series using `series.setData()`.

Comment: I have created a post method to update a partial view and I need the same data to update the chart as well then how can I do both at the same shot?

Comment: Could you put in a view JS? If soe use something like this: `$("#container").highcharts().series[0].setData(@Html.Raw(Model.seriesData))`.

Comment: it returns `$("#container").highcharts()` as undefined. It shows the error **Cannot read property 'series' of undefined**

Comment: Sorry, in your case use `chart1` instead of that.

Comment: @PawełFus The chart disappears if I do that... no errors in the console. Nothing but a white screen.

Comment: Could you tell me what do you have in console in that case: 'console.log(yourNewData);chart.series[0].setData(yourNewData);` ? Maybe there is something wrong with data? Also, do you have latest (3.0.7) version for Highcharts?

Comment: Yes i am using 3.0.7 version of the highcharts. Also I posted a question related to this. Please check the following link. [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411454/highchart-re-renders-0-values)

Comment: What is the purpose of creating exactly the same question second time? Users will close that related question. You haven't answered on my question - what is in console after adding my code?

Comment: [[ 'Wishlist Requests' , 21048], [ 'Approved Wishlists', 14047], [ 'Research Completed', 12387], [ 'Interview Scheduled', 5575], [ 'Successful Interview', 1625], [ 'Contract Signed', 111]]
This is the value of NewData in the console.

Comment: @PawełFus I created the new question because i had a new situation and new specifics to clarify the question a bit more on the basis of data.

Comment: Sorry, but for me it works fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/AS98x/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42661/discussion-between-vishal-and-pawel-fus)