# Highchart re renders 0 values

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, highcharts

I have a funnel highchart which initializes at the load of the page and initializes nicely and looks like:-

[image: correct highchart]

Now when I re initialize that high chart with the same method and new data, it looks like:-

[image: 0 value highchart]

Why is this happening? Does anyone has an idea about it?

**Update**:

The data I am having first time is:

[image: data for 1st time]

The data I am having second time is:

[image: data for second time]

Please help.

Thanks.

Regards
Vishal

Comment: Possible dupliate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386586/rerender-funnel-highcharts-with-new-data

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have not sorted data via x,ascending, what is required.

Comment: I made an edit to the question which is showing data I am having for the first time and the second time. It is in proper descending order.

Comment: You need to parse your data to correct figure, like in our example.

Comment: How to parse that data? Can you tell me the specific way to do that?

Comment: I advice to familiar with loops in javascript and then push points into new array, which will be correct ot highcharts.